# Compare two list of images and filter out repetition. (Swift)(iOS)

Tags: ios, swift, filter, control-flow

I have two lists of IDs (strings) which represent two sets of images. 
The viewSpaceArray are the IDs of the images already viewed by users. 
HomeViewData contains the entire collection of images.
The currentSpaceId is the IDs of the current image.
Number is the index of the items on HomeViewData 
What I want to do is to filter out viewed image until I get an "unviewed" one.

I managed to compare a single currentSpaceId to the list viewSpaceArray, but I don't know how to create a loop to go through a series of currentSpaceId until I find an unviewed item. Here is the code:
Thanks

```
func filterViewedSpaces() {
    viewedSpaceArray.removeAllObjects()
    var findViewQuery:PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "views")
    findViewQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{
        (objects: [AnyObject]!, error:NSError!) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            for object in objects {
                let upload:PFObject = object as PFObject
                let spaceId = upload["spaceId"] as String                        
                self.viewedSpaceArray.addObject(spaceId)
            }
        }
    }

    var currentSpace:PFObject = self.homeViewData[self.number] as PFObject
    var currentSpaceId = currentSpace.objectId as String!

    for object in viewedSpaceArray {
        let vSpaceId = object as String
        if currentSpaceId == vSpaceId {
            number++
        } else {
            loadData()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way using the set difference algorithm [found here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_difference):

```
/// Computes the relative complement of a with respect to b
func relative_complement<T: Comparable>(a a0: Array<T>, b b0: Array<T>) -> Array<T> {
    let a = a0.sorted { $0 < $1 }
    let b = b0.sorted { $0 < $1 }

    var result = [T]()

    var x = 0, y = 0
    while x < a.count {
        if y == b.count {
            return Array<T>(a[x..<a.count])
        }

        if a[x] < b[y] {
            result.append(a[x])
            ++x
        }
        else {
            if !(b[y] < a[x]) {
                ++x
            }
            ++y
        }

    }

    return result
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
let collection = ["a","b","c","d","e","f"]
let viewed = ["a","c","d","f"]

let relcomp = relative_complement(a: collection, b: viewed)
// relcomp contains ["b","e"]
```